# Proper models import from pytorch in keras

Tags: keras, pytorch

How to import this model from pytorch to keras? I write model from post bottom but Keras and pytorch models give different results.

```
class net_pytorch(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,Nin=6,Nout=1,Nlinear=112*60):
        super(vel_regressor, self).__init__()

        self.model1 = torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Conv1d(Nin,60,kernel_size=3,stride=1,groups=Nin),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
        torch.nn.Conv1d(60,120,kernel_size=3,stride=1,groups=Nin),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
        torch.nn.Conv1d(120,240,kernel_size=3,stride=1),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
        torch.nn.MaxPool1d(10, stride=6),
        )

        self.model2=model2=torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Linear(Nlinear, 10*40),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(10*40, 100),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(100, Nout)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.model1(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.model2(x)
        return x
```

How I write it in keras:

```
def net_keras():

  model2 = Sequential()

  model2.add(layers.SeparableConv1D(60, 3, strides=1, activation='relu', depth_multiplier = 6 , name = 'model1.0', input_shape=(200, 6)))
  model2.add(layers.SeparableConv1D(120, 3, strides=1, activation='relu', depth_multiplier = 6, name = 'model1.2'))
  model2.add(layers.SeparableConv1D(240, 3, strides=1, activation='relu', name = 'model1.4'))
  model2.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
  model2.add(layers.Dense(6720, activation='relu', name = 'model2.0'))
  model2.add(layers.Dense(400, activation='relu', name = 'model2.2'))
  model2.add(layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', name = 'model2.4'))
  model2.add(layers.Dense(3))

  model2.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='mae')

  return model2
```

I try to use [nn-transfer](https://github.com/gzuidhof/nn-transfer)  to convert but have error:

```
Layer names in PyTorch state_dict ['model1.0', 'model1.2', 'model1.4', 'model2.0', 'model2.2', 'model2.4']
Layer names in Keras HDF5 ['dense_1', 'global_average_pooling1d_1', 'model1.0', 'model1.2', 'model1.4', 'model2.0', 'model2.2', 'model2.4']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-a3986379ed2b> in <module>()
----> 1 transfer.pytorch_to_keras(pytorch_network, model2)

/content/nn-transfer/nn_transfer/transfer.py in pytorch_to_keras(pytorch_model, keras_model, flip_filters, flip_channels, verbose)
    122         for layer in pytorch_layer_names:
    123 
--> 124             params = util.dig_to_params(model_weights[layer])
    125 
    126             weight_key = layer + '.weight'

/content/nn-transfer/nn_transfer/util.py in dig_to_params(keras_h5_layer)
     23     # ['dense_2']['dense_3']['conv2d_7']['dense_4']['conv1']
     24     while not _contains_weights(keras_h5_layer):
---> 25         keras_h5_layer = keras_h5_layer[list(keras_h5_layer.keys())[0]]
     26 
     27     return keras_h5_layer

AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Also I try to use pytorch2keras but it dont work with groups != 1.

MMdnn also dont work with this model (error in image).

[MMdnn error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haLTI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error place :

```
model.add(layers.Conv1D(60, 3, strides=1, activation='relu', input_shape=(None, 200), name='model1.0'))
```

You should use `input_shape=(None,6)` unless your input is always `BatchSizex200x6`.

In addition, there are tools to convert models between different  architectures, e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn.

Comment: But how realize parameter groups=Nin? I already try to use pytorch2keras, but it dont work for my network. And I cant understand how to use MMdnn to convert source code model from pytorch to keras...

Comment: MMdnn not work too. `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'vel_regressor' on <module '__main__' from 'C:\\WinPy\\python-3.6.7.amd64\\Scripts\\mmconvert.exe\\__main__.py'>`